# MYSQL Filtering table upon sum of results in two other tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables in my database:

```
names: 
id |   name   |
---|----------|
 1 |   Mark   |
 2 |   George |
 3 |   Liza   |
 4 |   Tai    |

evaluation
name_id |   score  |
--------|----------|
 1      |    30    |
 1      |    100   |
 2      |    20    |
 3      |    40    |
 3      |    50    |
 4      |    40    |
 4      |    50    |

bonuses
name_id |   bonus  |
--------|----------|
 1      |    5     |
 1      |    1     |
 1      |    60    |
 2      |    2     |
 2      |    8     |
 4      |    12    |
 4      |    50    |
```

While you see each name has one or two evaluations, and many (or none) bonuses.

I need the MYSQL query to get the best evaluation.score and sum it with all the bonuses.bonus for same person and then order the names according to the total sum.

I tried the following but it seems I missing something:

```
SELECT 
    bonuses.name_id, 
    SUM(bonuses.bonus + evaluation.score) Total 
From bonuses, evaluation 
WHERE bonuses.name_id = evaluation.name_id 
group by names.id 
order by Total
```

Please help me to refer the problem in my query
Thanks

Comment: Can you display out put data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this demo out please:

- [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0776/14)

Query:

```
select n.id, n.name, 
(coalesce(max(e.score),0) +
coalesce(sum(distinct b.bonus),0)) as maxscorebonus
from name n
left join 
evaluation e
on n.id = e.name_id
left join 
bonuses b
on b.name_id = e.name_id
group by n.id
;
```

Results:

```
| ID |   NAME | MAXSCOREBONUS |
-------------------------------
|  1 |   Mark |           166 |
|  2 | George |            30 |
|  3 |   Liza |            50 |
|  4 |    Tai |           112 |
```

Comment: @xyro notice the usage of `distinct` in the query for `sum` that makes the difference :) Results are correct per your sample data :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT bonuses.name_id, SUM(bonuses.bonus + evaluation.score) Total 
FROM names, bonuses, evaluation 
WHERE bonuses.name_id = evaluation.name_id 
GROUP BY names.id 
ORDER BY Total
```

You were missing the table `names` in your FROM statement.

Comment: So, what are the results?!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    n.name as Name,
    IFNULL(SUM(e.score),0) + IFNULL(SUM(b.bonus),0) as Total
FROM names as n
LEFT JOIN evaluation as e ON n.id = e.name_id   
LEFT JOIN  bonuses as b ON b.name_id = e.name_id
GROUP BY n.id
```

### SQL FIDDLE DEMO

Comment: @xyro check this answer and demo. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  n.id, 
        (
        SELECT  COALESCE(MAX(e.score), 0)
        FROM    evaluations e
        WHERE   e.name_id = n.id
        ) +
        (
        SELECT  COALESCE(SUM(b.bonus), 0)
        FROM    bonuses b
        WHERE   b.name_id = n.id
        ) AS total
FROM    names n
ORDER BY
        total
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm joining `names` with `bonuses`, to sum all the bonuses for every user, and I'm joining with a subquery where I calculate the maximum score for every user. Then I sum the maximum with the sum of the bonuses:

```
select
  names.id,
  names.name,
  coalesce(max_score, 0) + coalesce(sum(bonus), 0) as total
from
  names left join bonuses
  on names.id=bonuses.name_id
  left join (
    select
      name_id,
      max(score) as max_score
    from evaluation
    group by name_id
  ) mx
  on names.id=mx.name_id
group by names.id,names.name
order by total desc
```

Coalesce is needed in case a user have no bonuses, or have no score.